# javascript regex not to allow non ASCII and backslash

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regular expression in JAVASCRIPT to allow a string which satisfies all the three below:

1. Can allow all characters except the special character "\"
2. Should not allow non ASCII characters

How can I get the regex for both of the above...

I have written regex as `^[0-9a-zA-Z' ']+$`, but this is allowing non ASCII.
I see online that `\x00-\x7F` allows non-ASCII chars, but how to combine both of these as a single regex?

Comment: Java is to Javascript is same as Car is to Carpet.

Comment: @RohitJain probably the best explanation I've heard to describe the differences between between Java and JavaScript.

Comment: ... like [Ham and Hamster](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/29/misunderstanding-markup-xhtml-2-comic-strip/) :)

Comment: *Should not allow non-ASCII characters* is better written as *Should only allow ASCII characters*.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
var match = str.match(/^(?:(?![^\x00-\x7F"]).)+$/);
```

Negative lookahead is used to to make sure each character is not non-ASCII OR `"`.

OR

```
var match = str.match(/^(?:(?!")[\x00-\x7F])+$/);
```

Negative lookahead is used to to make sure each ASCII character is not `"`.